# saving data in csv is not formatting as UTF-8 using python?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

Trying to **save the output in (append method) CSV data result in unformatted text, I tried UTF-8 encoding too but no help.**

[image: output excel]

sample text: Problem in new ITR portal, Finance Minister told Infosys- New Delhi Finance Minister Nirmala Sitharaman took the help

```
with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as fd:
    write = csv.writer(fd)
    write.writerow(transtext)
```

how should I append the data into Excel in a new row line each time?

Comment: Could you update your question with the csv file that was used to generate the rows from the Excel screenshot?

Comment: @DamianRobert it is totally an empty .csv, and I am trying to append all results into the file

Comment: You may need to specify UTF-8 when opening the file in Excel.  Also you may need to encode the csv with 'utf-8-sig' rather than 'utf-8'.